# Thymeleaf having 2 different list as model.addAttributes on one html page?

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Relatively new to Thymeleaf and Spring, I have a golf app where I show the rounds a user has played. Also at the top of this page is a drop down which has all the saved courses, from this dropdown you can select a course then you directed to the add a new round page for that course. Which works fine. I add both the list of courses and the list of rounds for a user from a RoundController using model.addAttribute(). The rounds list however doesnt work, and which will only be used to show recent rounds for the user.

I've added multiple attributes from a single method before, can someone tell me why it wont render 2 different lists now?

RoundController

```
  @GetMapping("/rounds/{id}")
    public String roundsHome(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id,
                             Model model) {
        List<Course> courses = courseService.getAllCourses();
        List<Round> rounds = userService.getUserById(id).getRounds();
        System.out.println("Rounds: " + rounds);
        model.addAttribute("courses", courses);
        model.addAttribute("rounds", rounds);
        return "/discgolf/round/rounds";
    }
```

rounds page

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="subContainer">
        <h1>Rounds</h1>
        <div id="username">
            <b>Username:</b> <span sec:authentication="principal.username"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a>Add Round</a>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/discgolf/newRound}" th:object="${course}"
          method="GET">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group blu-margin">
                <select th:name="course" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <option th:each="course : ${courses}"
                            th:text="${course.name}" >

                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <a>Rounds Played</a>
    ****The below div renders nothing!****
    <div th:each="round : ${rounds}">
        <label th:text="${roundDate}"></label>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Data that prints out from the @GetMapping

```
Rounds: [Round{roundId=5, course=Course{id=7, name='Legende', holes=[Hole{holeId=120, number=1, par=3}, Hole{holeId=121, number=2, par=3}, Hole{holeId=122, number=3, par=3}, Hole{holeId=123, number=4, par=3}, Hole{holeId=124, number=5, par=3}, Hole{holeId=125, number=6, par=3}, Hole{holeId=126, number=7, par=3}, Hole{holeId=127, number=8, par=3}, Hole{holeId=128, number=9, par=3}]}, scores=[Score{scoreId=36, score=1}, Score{scoreId=37, score=2}, Score{scoreId=38, score=3}, Score{scoreId=39, score=4}, Score{scoreId=40, score=5}, Score{scoreId=41, score=6}, Score{scoreId=42, score=7}, Score{scoreId=43, score=8}, Score{scoreId=44, score=9}], roundDate=2023-02-22 00:00:00.0}]
```

Hopefully its something easy, thanks in advance.

Comment: You are outputing `${roundDate}` instead of (presumably) `${round.date}` or `${round.roundDate}`.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I suck. Got it.